# karma + closure + coverage generating reports near the script files instead of targeted folder

Tags: code-coverage, karma-runner, google-closure

subj,

karma + closure + coverage,

have

```
coverageReporter: {
    type: 'html',
    dir: '../coverage/'
},
```

section, but coverage still place reports near the scripts files instead of coverage folder, only index.html & prettify.js & prettify.css placed in coverage/{browser}/ folder

How i can have all of them placed under /coverage/ folder?